# Munin 2 data not showing up on graph

Tags: fastcgi, munin, graph

I have a fresh installation of Munin 2.0.1 on my Ubuntu 12.04 and the first time I tried to view graphs, it showed them properly(After installation, I had to follow http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/CgiHowto2 to set it up)
After that, the graphs show up, but with with just one data point(single vertical line) as if no data is being collected after I tried it for the first time.

In Munin 1.4, there was munin-cron which was run every 5 minutes and I saw new data being plotted in the graph atleast every 5 minutes. But If there is no cron job in v2, How does data collection work with Munin2 ? Is the data collected when the graphs are requested ? The file timestamps in /var/lib/munin have not changed after the first time I tried the graphs. But i do see munin-node process running(restarted in several times). I also see no errors in the munin node log files or apache2 log files.

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Screenshot :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBkVD.png

Also, is there a way to pre-create graphs instead of doing it dynamically, on the fly ?

Answer (score 0):

Munin 2 also uses cron to collect data, so if you are missing data you should check that the cron script is running and that your munin-node is running.

Munin 2 allows for the graphs to be rendered on-demand, in previous versions graphs where rendered every 5 minutes, so this is a a great thing because it cuts down on processing power.
But it has to collect data from the nodes to be able to create the graphs on demand.